# Jenkins - Assign variable inside sh script

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, sh

I would like to create a variable name as POD inside script to assign kubectl output and then pass this variable while running kubectl port-forward pods..

But I received below error

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 151: illegal string body character after dollar sign;
   solution: either escape a literal dollar sign "\$5" or bracket the value expression "${5}" @ line 151, column 80.
   e-context ${KUBE_CLUSTER_STAGE}
```

---

Here is my script.

```
 environment {
                POD = ''
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'mbtkubeconfig', variable: 'config')]){
                        try {
                            // Expose PostreSQL
                            sh '''#!/bin/sh
                                chmod ug+w ${config}
                                export KUBECONFIG=\${config}
                                kubectl config use-context ${KUBE_CLUSTER_STAGE}
                                kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=database
                                POD = `$(kubectl get po -n database --selector='role==master' -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")`
                                kubectl port-forward pods/$POD 5432:64000 & echo \$! > filename.txt
                            '''
```

When I tried without variable there is no any error.Here is the script running without any error.

```
                        sh """#!/bin/sh
                            chmod ug+w ${config}
                            export KUBECONFIG=\${config}
                            kubectl config use-context ${KUBE_CLUSTER_STAGE}
                            kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=database
                            kubectl get pods -n database
                            kubectl port-forward pods/my-postgres-postgresql-helm-0 5432:64000 & echo \$! > filename.txt
                        """
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run commands with `sh` make sure you are using `"` not `'`. Groovy variables will only be resolved when using `"${config}"`.

By the way, it is considered best practice to mark variables with `env.` although not needed to resolve the variable. For instance, try to mark your cluster stage with `${env.KUBE_CLUSTER_STAGE}`